# MySQL 5.1 Order by query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, xampp

I am trying to run this order by query, and i cannot seem to figure out what the problem is.  From what I can tell, this should work.  I get no errors whatsoever but the order of the table does not change.

the table has 6 columns which are all of type char and an unsigned auto_incrementing ID.
the last_name column in the query is of type char(25).

```
$query="SELECT * FROM employees Order BY last_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Three option (1) query failing, show error, (2)Query is not ordering, paste sample data, and, (3)Query is not at all executing, show PHP code.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your results?

Comment: So what is the problem? Show us some sample data and the results of the query.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your table as well?

Comment: If changing your code doesn't change anything, it's probably because you aren't changing the file you think you are. Try changing it to "SELECT jdksjkaf FROM dajgkljdasg" and see if you get an error. If you still get the same result it's because you the file you are editing isn't the file that is being executed.

Comment: type char or type varchar? If char, why? Do you have any charset or charset collations defined?

Comment: couple of formatting issues, may or may not relate to the issue. Put all MySQL syntax in capitals, so ORDER BY last_name and also define ASC or DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"but the order of the table does not change"

How are you getting the results out of $result to populate the table? If you simply output the results using print_r are they in the expected order?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) echo $row['last_name'] . "\n";
```

Comment: I am printing using a php function i created called display to put it in an html table.  The function order i created is called before display.  i have not tried using print_r yet

Comment: when i use the function that you gave me, it puts them in the correct order.  but problem arises becuase i want to call the function order then display... this really helped me figure out my problem, thanks..i changed the way my program run..i call the function order, which calls display($results) and it works....thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = "...";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Mysql error: " . mysql_error());
```

instead. Without any error checking of this sort, we can NOT help you. The query looks syntactically valid, but there's far to many other reasons for this to fail to just sit here and guess all day. Never ever assume a query succeeds. Always check for errors.

Comment: i already have that line in my code, i just didnt feel it was necessary to put in the question